# Ошибка 1603 при установке Java 8+ 86/64 на Windows 10 1903 x64

Tags: java, windows, install

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Windows 10 Pro 18362.356 x64 (не сборка - лицуха)

Пробовал:
1) От админа/в режиме совместимости
2) Перезагрузить комп и отключить все браузеры и приложения, которые могут использовать java
3) Отключение антивируса и защиты Windows (брэндмауэр и defender)
4) Offline installer
5) KB2918614 в системе отсутствует.
6) Установку в другую папку (на диск D итд)

В журнале пишет для 86 `Product: Java 8 Update 221 -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action installexe, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221\installer.exe, command: /s INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221\\" INSTALL_SILENT=1 REPAIRMODE=0 ProductCode={26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180221F0}`

Для 64 `Product: Java 8 Update 221 (64-bit) -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action installexe, location: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\installer.exe, command: /s INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\\" INSTALL_SILENT=1 REPAIRMODE=0 ProductCode={26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180221F0}`

Ошибка Application Error 1000

**Имя сбойного приложения: jre-8u221-windows-x64.exe, версия: 8.0.2210.11, метка времени: 0x5d1e0139
Имя сбойного модуля: ntdll.dll, версия: 10.0.18362.356, метка времени: 0xf24fc044
Код исключения: 0xc0000005
Смещение ошибки: 0x000000000003fbe5
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x8d8
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d5713a9eef77b3
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jds2800031.tmp\jre-8u221-windows-x64.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Идентификатор отчета: 4c4de31a-8fb1-46be-afe2-e6e6b4b82160
Полное имя сбойного пакета:
Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом:**

До этого ставил последний Java 7 - корректно поставилось, но я его удалил полностью + почистил реестр, так как требуется именно 8 версия. Но проблема установки, т.е. ошибка была и на чистой винде, где java и в помине не было.

Comment: может дистрибутив кривой? Попробуйте его заново скачать.

Comment: @tym32167 тогда значит, он у oracle кривой - брал отсюда https://www.java.com/ru/download/win10.jsp

Comment: С `1603` я продолжаю до сих пор воевать в разных продуктах во время установки. Обычно - какой-то другой процесс дёргает `msiexec`. Попробуй ребутнуть машину и сразу же начать ставить яву.

Comment: Зачем вы на 64-битную систему ставите 32-битную JRE?

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev а что, это не законно?

Comment: @RupertSmith нет, просто странно и непонятно.

Comment: @don-rumata не помогло

Comment: Кстати да. Я проморгал про x86 в отличии от @RupertSmith. Попробуй 64 воткнуть.

Comment: @donRumata Product: Java 8 Update 221 (64-bit) -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action installexe, location: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\installer.exe, command: /s INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\\" INSTALL_SILENT=1 REPAIRMODE=0 ProductCode={26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180221F0}

Comment: @donRumata ещё одну ошибку вижу https://justpaste.it/7quuz + обновил описание

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev попытался поставить 64 - тот же результат. До этого вы спрашивали, почему 86. Как видите, разницы никакой. Хотя x86 должна работать в Win 64

Comment: Воткни чистую win10 на виртуалку и воткни этот же бинарник.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась путем установки windows 10 1809.